# I can't view my JPEG images in my windows 7

Tags: windows-7, images, sd-card

I have a Canon EOS 1100D and Apacer SD card, I transferred my images to my laptop windows 7 by inserting my SD card to my laptop. I can view the other images but the other cannot. It says "Windows photo viewer can't open this picture because either photo viewer doesn't support this file format, or you don't have the latest updates to Photo Viewer" I already installed some software to fix the problem but nothing happens it says error. When I insert back the SD card to my canon the canon can't read the SD card. But I actually copied the pictures that cannot be viewed in my laptop.

Comment: are you sure your SD card works well?

Comment: What is the file format? And did you try to view them with other apps.?

Comment: Also, why aren't you using a USB cable to transfer the files? That is the usual way and won't confuse the camera.

Comment: @user3169 That shouldn't matter for the camera, it's normal to swap SD cards (so basically change their contents).

Answer (score 1):

Ann, though I'm not sure what you mean by "I can view the other images but the other cannot," here are some questions to help us answer:

1. **How did you try to transfer the images?** If you used Windows Explorer **move**, then that may have left the card in a state that cannot be read by the camera. Use Windows Explorer **copy**, instead, or use another application to copy images from the card. In any case, *eject* the card using Windows Explorer before removing it.
2. **Were all images successfully copied to the laptop?** Can they be all be viewed from the laptop? If *Photo Viewer* cannot display them you might try installing and using free [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/).
3. **If all images can be viewed from the laptop, is the issue that you cannot load the card and see them in the camera?**

In any case, *after you have salvaged as many images as possible* from the card, it needs to be formatted in the laptop. *This will erase all images on the card, but is needed to make it usable.* Open Windows Explorer, right-mouse-click on the icon for the SD card and format it to its default settings. The camera should be able to read the card, but you may then need to format it *again* in the camera to install required folders.